# count the records that comply with the fact that the value of a field can only contain one type of incident

Tags: mysql

Having the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE contacts_cstm (
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Id_c INT NOT NULL,
    Department_c varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

And having `contacts_cstm` data like this

```
Id  Id_c    Department_c
1   1       ^pro^
2   2       ^pro^,^pro^
3   3       ^pro^,^temp^,^pro^
```

I want to count all the data in the contacts_cstm table. where the value of the `department_c` field includes ^pro^, or where there is more than one incidence of ^pro^ like the second row, but it should not participate in the account if it includes other items different from ^prop^

The expected output is 2, for registers that include `^pro^` and `^pro^,^pro^`

I have created this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d58f94/2)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure does not make any sense. Storing a comma separated list of departments in `Department_c` is obviously a bad idea (see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1191247)) and requires string manipulation and a full table scan to get the answers you want. To make this even worse, you have stored this serialised relationship in a separate table with a meaningless surrogate PK, when you already have `Id_c` (presumably FK to `contacts.Id`?).

It is not totally clear from your question what you are trying to do here, but it seems likely that this data would be better represented by `contacts (Id, Name)`, `departments (Id, Name)` and `contact_department (contact_id, department_id)`. This can be queried much more efficiently as it can effectively use indices, instead of requiring full table scans.

That said, with your current structure, you can improve on [P.Salmon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77378336/1191247) slightly by removing the need for the index scan for the outer `count(*)`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM contacts_cstm
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(department_c, '^pro^', ''), ',', '') = '';
```

This assumes that you would not have a row in `contacts_cstm` where `department_c` is an empty string. If the empty string is a possible scenario, you can add a criterion to exclude the empty strings:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM contacts_cstm
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(department_c, '^pro^', ''), ',', '') = ''
AND department_c <> '';
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ll9RLZZP).

Comment: thanks for the observation. Unfortunately it is a legal database from which I must obtain information

Answer (score 1):

using replace to identify exclusions

```
 select count(*) - 
(SELECT  count(*) as exclusions from contacts_cstm
where replace(replace(department_c,'^pro^',''),',','') <> '') pros
from contacts_cstm;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/5NVZIHaL